# Can individual tracking points be edited in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, tracking

I solved a rather long scene in After Effects for camera tracking.  Later, I realized that the tracking point I chose "jumped" out of its stable position for a split second.  This only became apparent *after* I had attached a graphic to that point.

Re-doing the analyze/solve steps is rather time consuming.  I was wondering if the tracking data for the point I have chosen is accessible and whether it is possible (and easy) to edit out the offending data point/points.

Answer (score 1):

(I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation yet lol)

By the way, if I got what you mean **you just have to move with the *Selection Tool* the keyframe on the Composition screen.**

For making the path smoother and more accurate the *sub-Pen Tool* called *Convert Vertex Tool*.

Finally, on the timeline thanks to *Graph Editor*, add dynamicity to the animation in-between frames (delay and advance).

Comment: Is your answer related to fixing the problem manually?

Comment: Yes, automatically I think you can just change the parameters of the tracer (that I'm sure you tried). If omething "jump" usually are few frame, otherwise you should change the point to track because that is not good.